# Revert to standard Stack Overflow webpage interface (no animation)

Tags: web, stack, overflow

I want to disable the animations on the Stack Overflow web site. I don't want those glittery shiny thing appearing on mouse hover and all other animations. I am thinking that this animation is slowing down my browser. (I have a poor Internet connection due to using a jumpserver to access another remote server).

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Wait until after April 1, 2019.
2. Or, if you don't want to wait, click the clock icon in the top nav bar.

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326036/announcing-the-stack-exchange-time-machine

Comment: Thank you. Have an awesome day. (By the way, if I get it correctly its only up until April 1st? I though of the same but its already April 2, 2019 in our server but I still have those animations.)

Comment: [They try to be generous with timezones on April 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320233/3345375), starting early and ending late. Likewise with Winter Bash: "14 hours before and 12 hours after the specified date in UTC." Bottom line is, it's still April 1 somewhere.